# Rotate 7 times then Ease

Tags: css, css-animations

Hello I am trying to animate an element so that it spins 7 times then slows down and eases I have the spinning done I just need to ease it. I am using a from and to keyframe to spin it, would I need to do it frame by frame or is there another way?

```
@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
.spin.animated {
    animation-name: spin;
    animation-duration: 400ms;
    animation-iteration-count: 7;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

Comment: This sort of 'multiple animation' is best suited to javascript. at best you could apply 2 animations..one with 6 rotatations and no ease, the second with 1 rotation and an ease with a suitable delay so that it doesn't start until the first has ended. See why Js is easier?

Comment: Im trying not to use JS

Comment: Sometimes, you just gotta if you want this kind of effect.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You mean like this:

```css
.spin {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform:rotate(2520deg);
    }
}
.spin.animated {
    -webkit-animation-name: spin;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2800ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="spin animated"></div>
```

Or even better:

```css
.spin {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
}

.spin:hover {
    transform:rotate(2520deg);
    transition: transform 3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="spin"></div>
```

Comment: If the initial class already has transform applied, make sure all transform properties are present or the animation might not work as expected. For instance, if you have both rotate and translate transition, but only want to transition rotate, also include translate with 0px value.

Answer (score 0):

In the `to`, give another animation:

```
@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
        animation: ease;
    }
}

@keyframes ease {

}
```

You might need to tackle the iteration count here. It should happen only after the 7 animations. So, I am not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

You have it pretty much all the way there.

```
.spin.animated {
        animation-name: spin;
        animation-duration: 400ms;
        animation-iteration-count: 7;
        animation-timing-function: ease; /* your timing function is where you tell it how to animate */
    }
```

here is list of all available calls: 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-timing-function.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a cubic bezier timing function.

Something like

```
cubic-bezier(0.81, 0.95, 0.84, 0.95)
```

will give an effect like the one that you are searching. There is a linear animation most of the time, and then it slows down

You can try different values, and set it graphically, here

[bezier curve tester](http://www.css3beziercurve.net/)